# How to get last insert id from spring repository insert (msyql)

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

I want to get the id of the 'categoria' inserted in mysql database from spring web application, here is my serviceImpl class from spring.

```
package com.tomatubuk.Service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;    

import com.tomatubuk.Entidades.Categoria;
import com.tomatubuk.Repository.CategoryRepository;

@Service
public class CategoriaServiceImpl implements CategoriaService{

@Autowired
private CategoryRepository categoriarepository;

@Override
public Iterable<Categoria> ListAllCategoria() {
    return categoriarepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Categoria saveCategoria(Categoria categoria){
    return categoriarepository.save(categoria);
}

@Override
public Iterable<Categoria> ListAllOrderASC() {
    return categoriarepository.findAllOrderASC();
}

@Override
public Iterable<Categoria> ListAllOrderDESC() {
    return categoriarepository.findAllOrderDESC();
}


}
```

And here is my catrgoria repository, which is called from my serviceImpl class

```
package com.tomatubuk.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.tomatubuk.Entidades.Categoria;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Categoria, 
Integer> {

@Query("Select c from Categoria c order by c.nombrecategoria asc")
public Iterable<Categoria> findAllOrderASC();

@Query("Select c from Categoria c order by c.nombrecategoria desc")
public Iterable<Categoria> findAllOrderDESC();

}
```

Thank you in advance